# Stored Procedure to create table using Data table and table name as parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will accept DataTable and Table name as  parameters and creates a table. This is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPROC_IMPORT_UPLOADED_EXCEL_DATA]
    @DataTbl emTable READONLY ,
    @TableName [varchar](50)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Check 1: Checking if the table is already present
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

IF OBJECT_ID (@TableName,'U') IS NOT NULL
        SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @DataTbl
    ELSE
        SET @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO ' + @TableName + ' FROM ' + @DataTbl

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

The following error is displayed:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SPROC_IMPORT_UPLOADED_EXCEL_DATA, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 7]
Must declare the scalar variable "@DataTbl".
```

After researching the error, tried to modify the procedure by adding the parameters to sp_executesql.

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
    N'@DataTbl emTable READONLY' ,
    '@TableName [varchar](50)',
    @DataTbl,
    @TableName;
```

However, the same error is displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: why you use `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL` not `EXEC (@SQL)`?

Comment: @LONG I would prefer to use sp_executesql because it allows for parameters. Of course in this situation you can't use parameters. :)

Comment: Check my answer @H.Bandi, I modified based on your SP

Comment: I used EXEC (@SQL). It gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are running into here is due to variable scope. Your table valued parameter is out of scope in the dynamic sql. However, if you use a temp table you can get around this issue because a temp table will still be in scope in your dynamic sql.

Something like this should get you close. Notice the use of QUOTENAME. This will greatly help minimize the risk of sql injection. I would suggest changing the datatype of @TableName to sysname instead of varchar(50).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPROC_IMPORT_UPLOADED_EXCEL_DATA]
@DataTbl emTable READONLY ,
@TableName [varchar](50)
AS
BEGIN

select *
into #TempData
from @DataTbl

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Check 1: Checking if the table is already present
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

IF OBJECT_ID (@TableName,'U') IS NOT NULL
    SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' SELECT * FROM #TempData'
ELSE
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' FROM #TempData'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPROC_IMPORT_UPLOADED_EXCEL_DATA]
    @DataTbl [varchar](50) ,
    @TableName [varchar](50)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Check 1: Checking if the table is already present
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

IF OBJECT_ID (@TableName,'U') IS NOT NULL
        SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @DataTbl
    ELSE
        SET @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO ' + @TableName + ' FROM ' + @DataTbl

EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

When you try to exec this procedure: use `EXEC SPROC_IMPORT_UPLOADED_EXCEL_DATA @DataTbl = ..., @TableName=...`

Updated:

If you need to parse a table variable, declare `@Table Table(col, type...)` or either create a **User Defined Function** to return a table result

Comment: I am pretty sure that @DataTbl is a table valued parameter not a string value.

Comment: No matter what @DataTbl type is, base on  `SELECT * FROM  + @DataTbl`, it should be a varchar

Comment: Right. But they are passing a table valued parameter not a string. As such while this is an excellent example of how to do this with a varchar, it won't work for the OP. To be honest, what the OP is a flawed concept.

Comment: So I was confused xD